# Vanisher - Mage breaking chemical bonds with power of his blood

Tags: magic, balancing-magic-systems

I have a mage discipline which focus on what is perceived as Vanishing. In reality they just teleport stuff by breaking chemical bonds and moving it. The limitation here is that the teleportation transports object's volume into the Wand/staff. Teleported volume can be calculated by taking tool's diameter and use it to calculate volume of sphere. Tool can absorb only volume equal to it's own volume. If the capacity is reached the tool is still working but the volume is transported into Vanisher's blood circulatory system (The magic is powered by blood - volume for volume)

I know body can process certain periodic elements and even utilize it. Like Calcium, Iron, Zinc. But I can imagine the mage would not want hit thermometer.

Example:

Two mages are fighting and one has full wand and miss his next shot. He hits water and now there are Hydrogen and Oxygen atoms from 5ml of water in his blood.

**Would there be any consequence for body? What periodical elements might cause sickness or even lethal effect if appeared in blood.**

Answer (score 2):

Most elements would cause severe effects if materialized in blood, except molecular oxygen, nitrogen, hydrogen and noble gases (with the exception of xenon, which would cause unconsciousness - no one exactly knows why, though Roger Penrose et al. believe it may be a quantum mechanical effect; the same goes, not so markedly, with argon and krypton).

Potassium, sodium and calcium would cause cardiac arhythmia and possibly death. Heavy metals would, well, cause a heavy metal poisoning, but the effects are long term (your wizard would get saturnism, dementia and possibly gout).

Depending on the physical form in which elements materialize, the effect could be immediately lethal. For example, sodium and potassium in elementary form react violently with water (and blood). A wasted spell could very well literally burst your heart. Elemental hydrogen is *the* protonator, and would cause chemical burns (and blood acidosis, but at that point probably it would matter little). In elemental form, even oxygen is potentially deadly, since it constitutes the [superoxide anion](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/superoxide); we even have a specialized enzyme, superoxide-dismutase, whose job is to get rid of dangerous oxygen forms.

Appearing as they do in the blood, most elements would be readily lethal because even a localized haemolysis (from, say, elemental carbon) will cause thrombotic formation, which means that your wizard will risk either dying or getting mentally impaired by a TIA. Far from the brain, he still risks [DVT](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/deep-vein-thrombosis/symptoms-causes/syc-20352557), which is not immediately life-threatening but still nothing to laugh at.

Comment: That is much harsher then I imagined. I might revert to original idea where they just simply break chemical bonds without teleportation. Just with cost of blood - that appears balanced enough instead of one miss - 90% death and 9% permanent mental impairment. (BTW this was excellent answer from you )